# Javascript file not linking to html

Tags: javascript, css, html, automatic-ref-counting

Hello I finished all of my code but my Javascripts aren't showing to my html but I am sure that I have linked them correctly. Can I have a extra set of eyes to see what I am doing wrong? If you can that would be great because I am not very good at javascript, thanks.

```js
*I have two Java script files in here because I have one for my main javascript and ball*

//ball.js


function ball()
{
//The ball itself
this.startAngle=0;
this.endAngle=360*Math.PI * 2;
this.radius=40;
this.drawBall = true;

//location for my ball
this.x = canvs/width/2;
this.y = canvas/height/2;

//coloring my ball
this.color = " #00FFFF";


//draw function

this.draw = function()
{
context.fillStyle = this.color;
context.beginPath();
content.arc(this. x,this. y, this. redius, this.startAngle, this.Endangle, this.drawBall);
context.fill();
 
}
 
 
 
 }
 
 
 //My main Javascript
 
 //Variables to use
var canvas;
var context;
var ball;

canvas = documnet.getElementById("canvas");
context = canvas.getcotnext("2d");

//Creates my ball function based off of what is on canvas for ball
var = ball = new Ball();

ball draw()
```

```html
​​<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" >
<title>Robert's Ball Game</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href = css/robs.css" />
</head>

<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="720"></canvas>



</body>
//Javascript
<script type="text/javascript" src= "javas/ball.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src= "javas/rob.js"> </script>

</html>
```

Comment: Syntax error://Creates my ball function based off of what is on canvas for ball
var = ball = new Ball(); <--
shouldn't this be var ball = new Ball()

Comment: I fixed that but still nothing pops up...

Comment: check your browsers developer tools network tab to see what's happening when it tries to load those two .js files (i.e. is status 200? 404? something else) - also check the developer tools console for any other errors

Comment: are the two JS files in a folder called `javas` - being a sub-folder of the folder where the html file is?

Comment: Yes a subfolder

Comment: Your CSS ref at the top is missing a starting quote. Could be the source of your error. Also press F12, and check under "Network" to see if its trying to get the JS files. You should see the two requests there for the JS files. Whats the status message of these 2 requests? And close of the gaps between the properties between `src = ""` (goes for all properties in here).